# fix variable = variable in a batch file for a password

Tags: batch-file, passwords, batch-processing

in this batch file i am trying to created a program where the user can enter his or her desired password and use it when ever they open or close the Batch file.
the problem is that i can not get the user password and (at :MDLOCKER and :UNLOCK) and the unlock part of the script to work. when finally get it to work it accepts any password
if you could help that would be great thanks.

```
enter code here@ECHO OFF
prompt Filelocker`enter code here`
:START
echo what do you want to do?  (insert number)
echo 1 Lock current folder
echo 2 Unlock current folder
echo 3 Make new locked folder

set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==1 goto CONFIRM
if %cho%==2 goto UNLOCK
if %cho%==3 goto NEW
echo not valid
goto start

: NEW
title Folder Locked files
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto ALREADY
if NOT EXIST Locker goto MDLOCKER

:ALREADY
echo folder already exist!
echo try unlocking if folder can not be found
pause
goto START



:CONFIRM
echo Are you sure u want to Lock the folder(Y/N)
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
if %cho%==y goto LOCK
if %cho%==n goto END
if %cho%==N goto END
echo Invalid choice.
goto CONFIRM


:LOCK
ren Locker "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder locked
goto end

:MDLOCKER
md Locker
echo Locked folder created....
echo folder is now created 
echo enter password for your file.
set/p 1%=
echo password accepted 
goto start




:UNLOCK
echo Enter password to Unlock folder
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT %pass%==%1% goto FAIL
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Locker
echo Folder Unlocked successfully
goto End


:FAIL
echo Invalid password
echo 2 MORE TRYS LEFT
pause
goto 


:End
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the positional parameters `%1` .. `%9`. Try saving your password into a variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:

```
set/p 1%=
```

Why are you doing that?

You can't use a special var like a var-name.
And you can't use numbers at the start of a var-name.

and you can use the command Choice instead of all the IF statements that you are using:

```
@ECHO OFF
prompt Filelocker`enter code here`
:START
echo what do you want to do?  (insert number)
echo 1 Lock current folder
echo 2 Unlock current folder
echo 3 Make new locked folder

choice /C 123 /M "choose an option: "
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (goto :CONFIRM)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 (goto :UNLOCK)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 3 (goto :NEW)

:NEW
title Folder Locked files
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" (
    echo folder already exist!
    echo try unlocking if folder can not be found
    pause
    goto :START
)
if NOT EXIST "Locker" (goto :MDLOCKER)

:CONFIRM
choice /C YN /M "Are you sure u want to Lock the folder? "
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (goto :LOCK)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 (goto :END)

:LOCK
ren Locker "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder locked
goto :end

:MDLOCKER
md "Locker"
echo Locked folder created....
echo folder is now created 
echo enter password for your file.
set/p "VAR=>> "
echo password accepted 
goto :start

:UNLOCK
echo Enter password to Unlock folder
set/p "pass=>> "
if NOT "%pass%"=="%VAR%" goto FAIL
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Locker
echo Folder Unlocked successfully
goto End

:FAIL
echo Invalid password
echo 2 MORE TRYS LEFT
pause
goto :UNLOCK

:End
```

Comment: "You can't use a special var like a var-name" Not true. A var-name may have any form and may include _any character_ excepting equal-sign, although some characters may cause certain management difficulties (like percent-sign). "And you can't use numbers at the start of a var-name" Wrong again, just type this in the command line to confirm it: `set 1%=Value of 1% variable` and `set 1`. See: [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3980) for further details.

Comment: omg, where you learned Batch?? Sorry but i need to say it: in EVERY programming language it's a RULE to not use a number as the first char of a variable name, if you use "set 1%=Value" like you said, that has ANY effect. learn about it please. and you can't define a variable name like a special var (ARGUMENT VAR %0 %1 etc) because they are all reserved by the system,

Comment: `c:\> set  1%=Value`  ; `c:\> set  1`  will produce `1%=Value`.You can also access the `1%` with enabledeyaedexpansion - `c:\>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` ; `c:\> echo !1%!` will give you `value`  .  Aacini is right.